# how to add + button for foreign key , similar to django's admin

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to implement + button for foreign key select field , if the foreign key doesnt exist instead of going to another page just pop up a form page to add new entry for the foreign key , i've implemented but its full size and dont go to the previous page when i submit the form : this is what i tried

```
class RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd(widgets.Select):
    def __init__(self, related_model, related_url=None, *args, **kw):
        super(RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        if not related_url:
            rel_to = related_model
            info = (rel_to._meta.app_label, rel_to._meta.object_name.lower())
            related_url = 'admin:%s_%s_add' % info
            self.related_url = related_url

    def render(self, name, value, *args, **kwargs):
        self.related_url = reverse(self.related_url)
        output = [super(RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd, self).render(name, value, *args, **kwargs)]
        output.append('<a href="%s?_to_field=id&_popup=1" class="add-another" id="add_id_%s" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);"> ' % \
            (self.related_url, name))
        output.append('<img src="%sadmin/img/icon_addlink.gif" width="10" height="10" alt="%s"/></a>' % (settings.STATIC_URL, 'Add Another'))
        return mark_safe(''.join(output))

class BookingVisitorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    visitor = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Vistor.objects.all().order_by('-pk'),empty_label='--------',
        widget=RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd(Vistor,related_url='')
    )
    class Meta:
        model = BookingVisitor
        fields = ['visitor','reason']
```

**updated**
this is screen shot of my window
[image]
**python 3**
**django 3.2**

is there something i did wrong ? or isnt there a better way to achieve it , but when i added a new visitor it should being selected in the foreign key drop down field ! thank you in advance ...

Comment: Could you try this? https://pastebin.com/evmHRLXQ

Read all the comments that I put there. Make sure o import site, get rid of render and change in the form the widget part. Let me know if worked.

Comment: @JoaquínDeTone thank you , i'll try it , let you know the result

Comment: @JoaquínDeTone no , still opens in the same window , and not shows any pop up form

Comment: Hmm, strange. Could you post your code on Pastebin , including the imports. Also, a picture of how is rendered, because it never happened to me that appears on the same window. I just tried using an adblock and chrome with popups option blocked, still worked the add button.

Comment: @JoaquínDeTone i post the screen shot of my window when i click on `+` , and my code is the same as yours

Comment: You are redirected to the page that you posted the screenshot after entered on "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Visitors/BookingVisitorForm/add/" and clicked on the Visitor field "+" button?

Comment: yes , and when i submit the form , it shows only an empty page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237427/discussion-between-joaquin-de-tone-and-hunar-mohammed).

Answer (score 1):

You can hardcode opening in a popup in your html page using JavaScript. `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper()` will wrap your HTML links `<a></a>` in a `.related-widget-wrapper-link.add-related` class.

```js
<script>
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.related-widget-wrapper-link.add-related');

// Add a click event listener to each link.
links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Prevent the default behavior of the link.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Open the link in a pop up window.
    window.open(link.href, '_blank', 'width=600,height=400');
  });
});
</script>
```